# How can I tell if the alarm is currently snoozing?

Tags: alarms

Sometimes I hit the snooze button instead of disabling the alarm when it goes off in the morning. Is there any way to tell which is the case afterwards without waiting for the alarm to possibly start ringing again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I accidentally hit snooze and want to avoid alarm to ring again I go to Alarms and make 2 steps. Disabled and enabled. I think it kills the snooze.

I think you cant know if one alarm is in snooze state.