# Switch off snooze

Tags: alarms

Related to [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/566), is there a simpler way to switch off snoozing than disabling and enabling the alarm clock?

Answer (score 2):

I could find no other easy way to just turn off snoozing. other than [this workaround here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/567/18061) you can use Cortana as a workaround.

1. Say "*Turn off Alarms*" to Cortana.
2. Then say which one.

[image]

**Note:** This will turn off the alarms and not just stop snoozing.